# comparison of if tag with swig in html of passed local model

Tags: html, swig-template

*I want to compare my `item.adminUse` which is in "true" or "False" which does not give correct out put*

**HTML**

```
{% for item in data%}
    <tr>
        {%if item.adminUse%}
        <td >{{item.id}}</td>
        <td >{{item.firstName}}</td>
        <td >{{item.adminUse}}</td>
     {%endif%}
    {%endfor %}
```

**Script**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    db('stdnt').find().done(function (err, models) {
        if ( err )
            console.log("Error in Index of Student:"+err);
        else
        console.log(models)
        res.render( 'stdnt/index',{data:models});//, { title: 'CRUD in Node', data:       models });
    });
};
```

*And this above is the controller that renders that link and sends that data "models"*

Comment: You might consider mentioning what output you do get (since you mention that what you are getting is not correct)... It might help to make your question more generally useful/informative

Comment: Please provide the values of `models` that you are passing to your view. What's "not correct"? What output do you expect? What output are you getting?

Comment: i am passing MODEL with values of stdnt DB of (firstname , lastname , id, admin use respectively all are 'string') but adminuse contains only true or false value but its type is also 'string' then why that if statement in if is not working on the basis of adminUse true or false value it should show those values which is the output i want .....thnxxxx

Comment: thnx .... did that in the controller .... what i was doing in the swig ....